# Can't Create a View Projection with Two Nested Associations

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have a query that is taking a long time due to multiple relationships. So, I want to create a View to fetch only the necessary data and use JOIN Fetch to optimize this query. However, JPA is returning an error No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!.

Here is the definition of the view I created:

```
public interface BoatContractView {

  Integer getId();
  String getName();
  Boolean getMaintenance();
  Set<ServiceBoatView> getBoatServices();

 
  interface ServiceBoatView {
        Integer getId();

        List<ContractDocumentDto> getContracts();
  
        interface ContractDocumentDto {
            Integer getId();
            ContractType getContractType();
        }
  }
}
```

And the method within the provider:

```
@Query("FROM Boat b JOIN FETCH b.boatServices bs WHERE b.marina.id = ?1 AND b.active = true ")
List<BoatContractView> findBoatContractViewByMarinaIdAndActiveTrue(Integer marinaId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are seeing is because you are not using aliases in your query. You can try the following query instead:

```java
@Query("SELECT b.id as id, b.name as name, b.maintenance as maintenance, bs.id as serviceId, cd.id as contractId, cd.contractType as contractType FROM Boat b JOIN b.boatServices bs JOIN bs.contracts cd WHERE b.marina.id = ?1 AND b.active = true ")
List<BoatContractView> findBoatContractViewByMarinaIdAndActiveTrue(Integer marinaId);
```

This query uses aliases to map the results of the query to the fields in your view. You can then use these aliases to populate your view.